# Javascript: document.referrer

Tags: javascript

Say I have included `document.referrer()` in my website(`www.abc.com`) and I got redirected to  my site from `google.com`.

Will the above mentioned code help me to get `google.com`?

Comment: cant try bcoz i dont have any site. .:-(

Comment: try using jsfiddle.net, you can try out any script you need. Or you rcould even try it yourself on w3schools on there interactive tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_referrer

Answer (score 1):

The search results in Google are not direct links. For example [searching for `abc`](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=abc&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=1&cad=b) the first result actual link is:
`http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fabc.go.com%2F&ei=_0nCTeOMFYOVswbY7PyHAQ&usg=AFQjCNHN69w2aXwjgMlF4X6o9W3lKd4uZw`

The redirection is then made server side so the code in `abc.go.com` website might not get proper referrer.

Answer (score 1):

```
javascript:alert(document.referrer);
```

When you will insert it at address bar, the previous location will appear, like the addresses appear on address bar, like `http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php`. You can use it to make complex JavaScript operations, like regular expressions. I will give very simple example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer.search('google')==-1){
    alert('Not using Google');
} else {
    alert('Yes, from Google');
}
</script>
```